# Make a custom script run when it detects a new metasploit sessions

Tags: ruby, session, remote-access, metasploit, kali-linux

How could I make a script that runs when the metasploit handler receives a new session?
By the way, the script should check if a file exists, and if it doesn't, it should upload a file to the victim.
I'm pretty sure I know how to write the script, I just don't know how to make it run when the listener (handler) receives a session

Comment: What have you tried so far

Answer (score -1):

I found out how to do it. Use the AutoRunScript (advanced) option and it will work.